# Text Editor java Swing actionListener save file

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, text-editor, key-bindings

**Problem**
I am making a text editor in java using Swing. I have a button which saves the file, using this method:

```
private void save() {
        if (savedAs) {
            try {
                PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(savedAsFile);
                fout.print(textArea.getText());
                fout.close();
                this.setTitle("Text Editor - " + fileName);
                saved = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TextEditorFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `savedAs` boolean is true only when a file is first created, otherwise it just saves it without opening the save as file chooser. When I use the button everything works, however when I call the `save()` method from the key bindings it saves but due to this method:

```
private void textAreaKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    this.setTitle("Text Editor - *" + fileName);
    saved = false;
}
```

It adds the asterisk back on to the title. I want it to display it without the asterisk because it has been saved. How can I make sure that the textAreaKeyTyped method does not pick up input while the action listener is calling the save method.

Key bindings actionlistener:

```
public void initBindings() {
    textArea.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "actionMapKey");
    textArea.getActionMap().put("actionMapKey", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            save();
        }
    });
}
```

**Cause**
I think that the text area picks up input caused by the user typing CTRL + S, therefore puts the asterisk in the title.

Thanks!

Comment: fout.print(textArea.getText()); replace with textArea.write(more see in API), rest of question isn't clear without an SSCCE with hardcoded String value for JTextAreas model (Document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most robust way would be to keep a `String lastSaved` object.

When you do `save()` do:

```
lastSaved = textArea.getText();
```

Then in your `textAreaKeyTyped()` do:

```
boolean unchanged = textArea.getText.equals(lastSaved);

if (!unchanged) {
   // add *, enable save, etc
} else {
   // remove *, disable save, etc
}
```

This will have the added benefit that if a user reverses their changes their document will go back to a "not modified" state.

I would actually create a method `updateSaveState()` containing that code and have both save and the modified callback call `updateSaveState()`, removing the duplicated code there and putting all the logic for window title etc in one place.

I'd also be tempted to create an `isModified()` method that returns `!textArea.getText.equals(lastSaved)` and remove the saved flag completely. Anything that wants to know can just call `isModified()`.

Note that in this case the edit will not be applied yet at the point the keyTyped is received. If you do a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to delay your processing until after the keypress has been processed that should fix this problem.

Comment: Very well explained answer thank you. I am using your advice now!

Comment: For some reason it requires two edits to be made before the asterisk is added. I don't understand why?

Comment: I tried that where I thought it should go (in the actionListener):
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        save();
                    }
                });
            }  But it doesn't change anything. Am i putting it in the right place?

Comment: Close, but not quite (right idea, wrong function) - put it in `textAreaKeyTyped`. The problem is happening because the check for whether the string has changed is happening before the result of the key press has been processed and changed the string.

Comment: Ah I understand now thank you so much for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two choices:

1. Disregard the (Ctrl+s) key evt in your textAreaKeyTyped method. Maybe also disregard other key combinations that don't necessarily edit the text
2. Or set the title (without the asterisk) after you have saved